# Derivation of Blattner's conjecture in the Beilinson-Bernstein picture

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

On the last page of [Schmid's article "Discrete Series"](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Eschmid/articles/disc_ser.dvi), he says

"In the Beilinson-Bernstein picture, discrete series modules are attached to closed $K$-orbits in $X$... the $K_{\mathbb R}$-structure of discrete series modules [i.e. Blattner's conjecture, which Schmid proved] is almost obvious from this point of view."

I do indeed see how to prove Blattner's conjecture from this point of view, though there is enough battle with $\rho$-shifts that I didn't find it "almost obvious". (Added: I [posted this proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0038) on the arXiv.)

> Is there a place where Blattner's conjecture is derived in this algebraic setting of $(\mathfrak g,K)$-modules, rather than Schmid's original analytic setting?

(I did write Schmid, though I suspect if he knew of such a reference he would have referenced it. Of course one may have come out in the intervening time, and if he has an answer I will include it here.)

ADDED: Schmid's derivation sounded (on the phone) pretty isomorphic to mine, except where I write out a page (being an outsider to the field, and not clear on which parts are considered easy and which hard) he often puts just a sentence. Nothing wrong with that, of course, if you know your audience and know what will suffice for them. Anyway that doesn't answer my reference-request.

Comment: Does Havlíčková's dissertation contain the sort of result you want?  http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/43796

Comment: She references the Blattner formula, but doesn't derive it, as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 3):

"Geometric Methods in Representation Theory", by Gregg Zuckerman p.283, in 'Representation Theory of Reductive Groups' ed. Peter C Trombi, Progress in Math. 290 Birkhauser(1983) Procedings of University of Utah conference may have what you are looking for.

Comment: It's definitely got some of the ingredients, and in particular, draws attention to the importance of K-orbits with smooth closure. It doesn't reference Blattner directly though. Thanks!